# C# unable to add DateTime to chart

Tags: c#, charts, datagridview, datagrid, datagridviewcolumn

Hi im trying to add data from a Datagridview to a linechart but the Column im trying to use for the X Axis is a DateTime Datatyp. I have tried to shorten the Value inside the Column (Substring) but it didnt work

I tried it with this code to implement the "TimeStamp" as X Axis for the Chart

```
private void Laden_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var objChart = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
            objChart.AxisX.IntervalType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DateTimeIntervalType.Auto;
            objChart.AxisX.Minimum = Convert.ToDouble(Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value).Substring(15, 5));
            objChart.AxisX.Maximum = Convert.ToDouble(Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1].Cells[0].Value).Substring(15, 5));

            objChart.AxisY.IntervalType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DateTimeIntervalType.Auto;
            objChart.AxisY.Minimum = 0.0;
            objChart.AxisY.Maximum = 1.0;

            chart1.Series.Clear();

            chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName;
            chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName;
            chart1.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
            chart1.Series[0].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
            
        }
```

[image: the datagridview]

I tried to Shorten the Value inside "TimeStamp" with a Substring and convert it to Double afterward so only the Seconds and Miliseconds would be displayed

`

```
objChart.AxisX.Minimum = Convert.ToDouble(Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value).Substring(15, 5));
            objChart.AxisX.Maximum = Convert.ToDouble(Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1].Cells[0].Value).Substring(15, 5));
```

`

Comment: What exactly is it that you're trying to do / what issue are you encountering. Is your issue the length / formatting of the DateTime? If so, take a look at `YourDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff")`. This removes the timezone information. `YourDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffffK")` displays that. Mix & match until you find the format you want to use.

Comment: _the Column im trying to use for the X Axis is a DateTime Datatyp. I have tried to shorten the Value inside the Column (Substring)_ This sounds a lot as if you are adding the x-values as strings. Never do that!! You need to make the x-axis value type DataTime and then add datetime values.  - Later you can tweak the formatting and the Intervals, but first add the data correctly, ie as DataTime.- (or as doubles from OaDate)

Comment: For a correct conversion you need to use [tooadate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tooadate?view=netframework-4.7.2)